# What does the phrase "patrol cleared areas for supply caches" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from a space action game:

> When you are away from the battlefield, you can send your co-soldiers
>   to patrol cleared areas for supply caches, while mining resources and
>   upgrading your equipment and base.

I am not very familiar with the phrase "supply caches". Maybe this is why the said phrase is not clear to me.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cache - meaning 1. A secret store of supplies

Comment: You should asked both of your question in one question, there is no need to split it into two.

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski That is not correct. One question per question. What if someone answers the first question correctly and the second question incorrectly? How do we vote on that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply cache is a some sort of crate or place in which supplies, probably military supplies in this case, are kept safe for later use.